# Workflow Rule Formulas

Tags: email, workflow

I have an automated email set up via workflow rules to send whenever there is a change to a certain field in the Opportunity Layout. But I want to filter that rule so it only sends whenever the Opportunity is on a certain stage.

This is what the current formula looks like

```
ISCHANGED(LRM__c)
```

I came up with a few other ones such as:

```
ISCHANGED(LRM__c) 

(Opportunity: StageName equals 02 - Scoping) and
(Opportunity: StageName equals 03 - Quoting) and
(Opportunity: StageName equals 04 - Solutioning & Deployment)
```

and:

```
AND ISCHANGED(LRM__c) 

(StageName : '02 - Scoping') ,
(StageName : '03 - Quoting') ,
(StageName : '04 - Solutioning & Deployment')
```

but neither of them seem to work. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
AND (
        ISCHANGED(LRM__c),
        OR ( 
             ISPICKVAL(StageName , '02 - Scoping') ,
             ISPICKVAL(StageName , '03 - Quoting') ,
             ISPICKVAL(StageName , '04 - Solutioning & Deployment')
           )
    )
```

I didn't checked this but formula would be similar to this.